# Xamarin.Forms projects never finish compiling in Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.6.1 and earlier versions

Tags: visual-studio, build, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0

Lately I have had problems compiling my Xamarin.Forms project which also has several web services projects in the same solution. I have been working on the project for several months and everything went well until I got to the point that the project, at the time of building, never finished compiling. I've even passed the same on new projects.

I have tried with several methods to solve this problem, but all useless to the case. For example, delete all the files in the TEMP folder, the WebsiteCache folder in the path C: \ Users \ you_user_name \ AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ WebsiteCache. Etc.

Has this problem happened to someone?

Please tell me your solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Image of build started project]

Comment: try deleting the .vs folder in the directory with your solution.  it is hidden by default

Comment: @KenTucker I tried your theory but it does not work.

Comment: Can you check for a newly created project in Xamarin.Forms. Then compile each and every project individually in your solution. Let me know what the response is.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck 'Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio' under Tools|Options|NuGet Package Manager Or save XAML changes, before building !

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/319616/vs2017-v158-build-hangs-if-files-not-manually-save.html

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of running the project before saving xmal file.

1. Tools => Options => NuGet Package Manager.
2. **Uncheck** 'Automatically check for missing packages during build'

Answer (score -1):

I’ve had similar problems when building Xamarin apps and found that running visual studio as administrator seems to fix the never ending compiling issue